# Linksys wusb600n support on Debian-6

Tags: debian, networking, drivers, wifi, hardware-compatibility

I'm on my way from Windows 7 to Debian 6. The only problem... I'm not sure about my network adapter. Its Linksys wusb600n and without it - no internet access for me.

- Does Debian 6 support it?
- Will it be supported without additional drivers (or what they are called)?

Comment: Follow up question here: [Firmware for wireless card on Ubuntu/Debian?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16329/1925)

Comment: @Caleb They both are my questions. xD Anyway, I can't find answer.

Comment: I know, the link is for the benefit of anybody else finding this thread and wanting to move on towards the final answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google results show quite a few people successfully using that stick. There seems to be a driver in the kernel that recognizes it but results are hit and miss, possibly due to v1 vs v2 of that product. Since most of these are from last year, I suspect it just works now. Some people say that [ralink's drivers](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Main_Page) work better. They have a stick that uses the same chipset as the Linksys and provide drivers that work, you just have to [change the recognized IDs](http://gordonazmo.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/getting-the-linksys-wusb600n-v2-usb-stick-to-work-in-linux/).

If things ever get really sticky, you can always use [ndiswrapper](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Main_Page) and the manufacturer provided Windows drivers. These days very few devices outright won't work.

The best thing to do is boot up a LiveCD and see if it works without making any changes to your system!

Comment: I think I'm going to play with Live CD to see... does it works; how to get it working!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, only Fedora can see the Cisco Linksys WUSB600N v2 and work. I tried Ubuntu, Debian, etc. and none of them supported this WiFi adapter