# How to make Wi-Fi work on Dell Inspiron 14R laptop running Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I have seen that on most Dell laptops running Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10, the Wi-Fi doesn't work.

It appears the reason for this is the fact that Dell laptops have Broadcom wireless cards. How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at this question, perhaps this works.

[Firmware for wireless card on Ubuntu/Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16329/firmware-for-wireless-card-on-ubuntu-debian?rq=1)

Also have a look at:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

This also seems to be similar:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312

Goodluck